# Only allow one decimal for each number in UITextView (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITextView` into which I type a series of space-delimited numbers (for example: "12.3 30 22.7 19.23 15 8.5 11").

The `UITextView` may contain multiple decimal points, but I want to ensure that no individual number contains more than one decimal place.

All the solutions I have found only restrict the entire `UITextView` to a single decimal, not each number.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final result:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    // only allow valid characters
    let validCharacters = " -0123456789.,|\t\n"
    guard CharacterSet(charactersIn: validCharacters).isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: text)) else {
        return false
    }
    
    let oldText = txtViewDataInput.text!
    let r = Range(range, in: oldText)
    let text = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: r!, with: text)
    debugPrint("text = \(text)")

    let whiteSpace = " ,|\t\n"
    let separators = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: whiteSpace)

    let tempArray = text.components(separatedBy: separators as CharacterSet)

    // do not allow more than one decimal point in a number
    for number in tempArray {
        let splitAtDecimal = number.filter { $0 == "." }.count
        if splitAtDecimal > 1 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this in the UITextView delegate func `shouldEndEditing`..

```
func textViewShouldEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    guard let numbers = textView.text else {
        return true
    }
    var hasMultipleDecimalPlaces: Bool = false
    let numbersAsList = numbers.split(separator: " ")
    for number in numbersAsList {
        let splitAtDecimal = number.split(separator: ".")
        if splitAtDecimal.count > 2 {
            if splitAtDecimal[1].count > 2 {
                // This is what you want to prevent so break early and return false
                hasMultipleDecimalPlaces = true
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return !hasMultipleDecimalPlaces
```

}

This will prevent the user from finishing editing the textview. It can always be used in a function like `shouldReplaceCharactersIn`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this delegate textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:) and by your self check every single number and check if there was already point or not. And return false or true.

Answer (score 0):

Try a regular expression in the text view delegate method:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^\\s*((-?)(\\d+\\.?|\\d*\\.\\d+))?(\\s+(-?)(\\d+\\.?|\\d*\\.\\d+))*\\s*$")

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    // Compute the value of the text view after the text is inserted.
    let finalText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text) as NSString
    // Check against a regular expression.
    return regex.firstMatch(in: finalText as String, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: finalText.length)) != nil
}
```

You are going to have to experiment with the behavior that you want:
https://regex101.com